# page refreshing after pressing on button to upload files with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload

I've this form and I want to send file and some other information via ajax to PHP file
My problem is when I try to download a file, the page refreshing after pressing on post, how can I prevent refresh page?

Also please I want to clearly understand what is this three options and for what I need each one exactly, I got it from here(stack overflow from another post) `contentType: false,` `cache: false,` `processData: false,`

When trying to upload without these three options I just got this error message in console log (illegal invocation).

```
<form action="" method="post" id="image-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="imgInp"/>
    <input type="text" id="postNum" name="postNum" value="<?= $postNum; ?>"/>
    <input type="button" id="sendImage" value="Upload"/>
    <div id="blah"></div>
</form>
```

```
$("#sendImage").click(function() {
    var thisData = $('#image-form')[0];
    console.log(thisData);
    $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fad fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Please wait...!</div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        url: "data.php?uploadImage=1",
        data: new FormData(thisData),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == 1 || parseInt(data) == 1) {
                $("#msg").html(
                    '<div class="alert alert-success"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> Data updated successfully.</div>'
                );
            } else {
                $("#msg").html(
                    '<div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Extension not good only try with <strong>GIF, JPG, PNG, JPEG</strong>.</div>'
                );
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            $("#msg").html(
                '<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> There is some thing wrong.</div>'
            );
        }
    });
});
```

```
$postNum= $_POST['postNum'];
$file = $_FILES['imgInp']['name'];
$file_image = '';
if($_FILES['imgInp']['name']!=""){
    extract($_REQUEST);
    $infoExt        =   getimagesize($_FILES['imgInp']['tmp_name']);
    if(strtolower($infoExt['mime']) == 'image/gif' || strtolower($infoExt['mime']) == 'image/jpeg' || strtolower($infoExt['mime']) == 'image/jpg' || strtolower($infoExt['mime']) == 'image/png'){
        $file   =   "Q-".$postNum.".".pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);;
        $path   =   'includes/images/uploads/specialUploads/'.$file;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imgInp']['tmp_name'],$path);

        $insert     =   1;
        if($insert){ echo 1; } else { echo 0; }
    }else{
        echo 2;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

to prevent the form submit, also put the whole code in JQuery document ready

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#sendImage").click(function(e) {
        var thisData = $('#image-form')[0];
        console.log(thisData);
        $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-info"><i class="fad fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Please wait...!</div>');
        /* ajax call */
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I just adds e to function and adding e.preventDefault(); return false; but problem not resolving! page refreshing

Comment: Sir `e.preventDefault();` `return false;` not working page still refreshing :(

Comment: You're right, I think put the listener in document ready should solve it, I edited the answer.